# Dell inspiron 15R turbo

Tags: battery, dell-inspiron

I have an inspiron 15R turbo model 7520. I ordered a new battery, but the one I got is 60wh. The original battery is 48wh. I am facing some problems, the laptop shuts down suddenly without any warning. While shutting down, it's making a small static sound. Sometimes the laptop works fine but sometimes it boots up and shuts down immediately. It doesn't go through the normal shut down process, rather it's as if some one pulled the plug while a desktop PC is on. I did not face any such problem with my previous battery. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your battery is not directly involved.

Do you have the same problem while using the power supply?

You are also taking about a "static sound". In the best scenario, it would be just the hard disk head parking noise, which is usual when the power supply is suddenly shut.

But it could also be a poor electrical contact between the battery backplane and the internal chips, you should check first if you don't see any trace of twisted connectors behind the battery.

At worse, if you do not notice any physical damage while trying to look behind the battery, it could be related to a defective internal chip or component in charge of the motherboard electrical supply stabilization. But in that case, only a professional will be able to make the additional tests and to tell you exactly what's going on.